# Explanation needed, for "Ask, don't tell" approach

Tags: design-patterns

I'm taking a course on pattern designs in software engineering and here I'm trying to understand the good and the bad way of design relating to "coupling" and "cohesion". I couldn't understand the concept described in the following image. 
[image]
The example of code shown in the image is ambiguous to me, so I can't quite clearly get what exactly "Ask, don't tell!" approach mean! Could you please get anything outta the image? If yes, please explain!

Thanks

Comment: I could be completely wrong, but it looks to me like it should be "Tell, don't ask," which is what the example says is better. [Tell, Don't Ask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc947917.aspx#id0070045) explains it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the first implementation the client code of the class is highly coupled to the implementation because the fact that the student list is implemented with a `SortedList` of some kind is leaked. Once the class is used from hundreds of other places, changing its internal implementation from `SortedList` to something else becomes hard or impossible. The second implementation keeps the implementation details hidden, leading to looser coupling.

I believe this principle is better known as [the law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). I have never heard of it being described as "ask don't tell."

Comment: Exactly, just in the preceding slide they talked about the "law of demeter".

Answer (score 1):

We have no idea what tum is, but that is fine; it doesn't matter. What matters is how you interact with it (what methods it has). For illustration purposes, let's say that tum is of type X.

In the bad example, we have to get a SortedList from tum, and start working with the SortedList. It's bad because you are tightly-coupling type X with SortedList. In the future, you may not want to use a SortedList (or a subclass of it). If you change X so it uses an array, database, web server, or anything else, you'll have many potential problems:

1. You have to change the code anywhere you are adding a student. For a small project, it may be only a few places. For larger projects, this could be used in hundreds of places, and can be a headache to change.
2. If you expose type X as a library to others to use, anyone using X will have to update their code. People using your library may be very upset if they have to update their code in many places.
3. Let's say SortedList changes and methods are added or removed (not likely with SortedList, but possible if it was another class you made). You'll have to update every place that is adding a student, even though you are only changing the data structure for how students are being held.

In the better example, addStudentToLecture(...) hides its implementation details. It may be using a SortedList, or it may be something else. Anyone who wants to add a student to tum doesn't need to know how to use a SortedList, and the implementation of addStudentToLecture(...) can change without changing the calling code.

Answer (score 0):

In the first (or bad) example you **tell** what to do.

You spell out the details of how to add a student to a lecture. Several things are wrong with this. The `tum` returns its internal implementation detail as a mutable object. The client can mess with it, possibly breaking invariants of the `tum` class. Perhaps that's the biggest flaw. Apart from that, you also depend on the details of how to get the students' list and on the details of how to add a student. If any of these details change, your code breaks...

In the second you **don't tell** how to do it. You instead **ask** the `tum` to do the work for you but you don't tell the details how to do it. It also means that if any of these implementation details change, your code is still OK; the `tum` implementation can change independently.

Hope this helps.